# When I set the window to non-opaque,the font look like changed

Tags: java, swing, fonts, window, blur

When I set the window to non-opaque,the font look like changed!Who can tell me why and help me ,thanks!
I guess this is affected by the "RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING",but I test in many way,and ther is no my desired result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 20, 10));
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Why this changed?"));
    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel() {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // super.paint(g);
            // ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.drawString("There is no change", 0, 15);
        }
    };
    lbl2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 22));
    mainPanel.add(lbl2);
    JPanel toolPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    final JCheckBox ckxWindowOpaque = new JCheckBox("WindowOpaque");
    ckxWindowOpaque.setSelected(!AWTUtilities.isWindowOpaque(frame));
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean b = AWTUtilities.isWindowOpaque(frame);
            if (b == !ckxWindowOpaque.isSelected()) return;
            if (b) {
                AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
            } else {
                AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, true);
            }
        }
    };
    ckxWindowOpaque.addActionListener(al);
    toolPanel.add(ckxWindowOpaque);
    toolPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Exit") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }));
    frame.getContentPane().add(toolPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Why are you extending `JLabel` to only paint the text any way?

Comment: This just is an example,in fact,my swing app using JTable.

Comment: This is a demo,only used for explain my problerm.

Comment: Okay, now I've had a play, I see what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been debugging and tracing my program,and I found the key code here:SwingUtilities2.drawString/drawChars/drawTextAntialiased.
So,I modified the JRE's code in the "SwingUtilities2.drawString/drawChars",I add code like this :

```
if (UIManager.getBoolean("MYLAF.AATextInfo.Disable")) {
    g.drawChars(data, offset, length, x, y);
    return nextX;
}
```

Finally,on the begin of my program,I add the setting "UIManager.put("MYLAF.AATextInfo.Disable",true)".

If you wan't modify the SwingUtilities2,you can use "myJComponent.setClientProperty(AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY,null)".

Answer (score 3):

This will have to do with how Swing/AWT deals with the different requirements between an opaque and transparent window and changes being made internally to the anti aliasing.

For example, if I use

```
((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

To render the text, I can get it to appear the same way when it's made transparent

[image: Transparent][image: Opaque]

I also get the same result from `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_DEFAULT`, `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_GASP`

But if I use `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HBGR` or `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB` it will act the same as the `JLabel` in both modes

These are system level decisions and I don't think you can effect them (easily).

You might like to take a look at [LCD Text: Anti-Aliasing on the Fringe](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983384), which is an interesting read, but I'm not sure it will help much...

Comment: I have been debugging and tracing my program,and I found the key code here:SwingUtilities2.drawString/drawChars/drawTextAntialiased.
So,I modified the JRE's code in the "SwingUtilities2.drawString/drawChars",I add code like this :

    if (UIManager.getBoolean("MYLAF.AATextInfo.Disable")) {
        g.drawChars(data, offset, length, x, y);
        return nextX;
    }

Finally,on the begin of my program,I add the setting "UIManager.put("MYLAF.AATextInfo.Disable",true)".